# Запятая перед определительным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, причастный-оборот

Выполняла диктант на Грамоте.ру. Встретила предложение.

В этот момент что-то дрогнуло в утробе(,) висевших в комнате(,) больших настенных часов, на которые он в течение ночи то и дело поглядывал сквозь раскрытые двери веранды.

Поставила запятую после слова "утроба". Мне выдает объяснение:
**Не обособляется определительный оборот ВИСЕВШИХ В КОМНАТЕ, стоящий перед определяемым словом ЧАСОВ** и одновременно после определяемого слова "утроба".

Вторая запятая объясняется так же. Но здесь все понятно. Я ее и не ставила.

Вопрос: почему не нужна первая запятая? Ведь определительный оборот "ВИСЕВШИХ В КОМНАТЕ" стоит одновременно и после определяемого слова "утроба", и перед определяемым словом "часы".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этот момент что-то дрогнуло в утробе **висевших в комнате** больших настенных **часов**, на которые он в течение ночи то и дело поглядывал сквозь раскрытые двери веранды.

Мне кажется, что Вы что-то путаете, когда говорите: *определительный оборот "ВИСЕВШИХ В КОМНАТЕ" стоит одновременно и после определяемого слова "утроба" и перед определяемым словом "часы".*

**У причастного оборота может быть только ОДНО определяемое слово**, в данном случае — это слово "часов" (оборот стоит ПЕРЕД ним, поэтому и не обособляется).

Достаточно перестроить предложение, чтобы это было четко видно:
В этот момент что-то дрогнуло в утробе больших настенных **часов** (каких?), **висевших в комнате...**

Answer (score 0):

В комнате висели часы (а не утроба), поэтому оборот "висевших в комнате" относится именно к часам. Оборот, стоящий перед определяемым словом, не обособляется.

Дополнение. Я изменил название вопроса "Запятая в опредлительном обороте", так как мы не обсуждаем запятые *внутри* оборота.